# Set image in a cell of Infragistics grid

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, infragistics

I need to set the image inside a cell of my grid. I have a column which is created in static and the other columns are bounded dynamically from database. With a certain conditions and looping of the dynamic values i have to set a image in the row of the static column.

//Code of static column created

```
 If UltraGridColumn.Tag Is Nothing And UltraGridColumn.Key = "TransactionStatus" Then

                        'Configure column
                        UltraGridColumn.CellActivation = If(Me.WorkflowsController.SelectedWorkflow.HasUpdateAccess, Activation.AllowEdit, Activation.ActivateOnly)
                        UltraGridColumn.CellAppearance.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
                        UltraGridColumn.CellAppearance.FontData.Bold = If(Me.WorkflowsController.SelectedWorkflow.HasUpdateAccess, DefaultableBoolean.True, DefaultableBoolean.False)
                        UltraGridColumn.CellAppearance.FontData.Italic = If(Not Me.WorkflowsController.SelectedWorkflow.HasUpdateAccess, DefaultableBoolean.True, DefaultableBoolean.False)
                        UltraGridColumn.ExcludeFromColumnChooser = ExcludeFromColumnChooser.True
                        UltraGridColumn.Header.Caption = "Transaction Status"
                        UltraGridColumn.Header.ToolTipText = "Transaction status."
                        UltraGridColumn.Hidden = False
                        UltraGridColumn.Style = ColumnStyle.DropDownList
                        UltraGridColumn.ValueList = Me.WorkflowsController.StatusesController.StatusesValueList
End If
```

//Code to set the image

```
Dim transId = TransactionCommentsCollection.Select(Function(x) x.TransactionId)
                Dim transLevelId = transId.Intersect(TransactionLevelCommentsCollection.Select(Function(x) x.TransactionId))
                If (transLevelId.Contains(Record.TransactionId)) Then
                    //Get the corresponding cell here

                    'Set the cell image
                    UltraGridCell.Appearance.Image = My.Resources.Tran_comment_16
                    UltraGridCell.Appearance.ImageHAlign = HAlign.Right
                    UltraGridCell.Appearance.ImageVAlign = VAlign.Top

                End If
```

How to get the row and cell of the column created statically and set the image?

Comment: UltraGridColumn and UltraGridCell are the names of the classes. They are not valid references to an actual column or cell. You need to use something like: `UltraGridColumn col = grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[[TransactionStatus"]` for a column with the desiderd key and `UltraGridCell cell = grid.ActiveRow.Cells["TransactionStatus"]`

Answer (score 0):

Since your column has a ValueList you can use the Appearance of the ValueListItems to set the image and then set the [DisplayStyle](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.v13.1~Infragistics.Win.ValueList~DisplayStyle.html) of the ValueList to be [Infragistics.Win.ValueListDisplayStyle](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.v13.1~Infragistics.Win.ValueListDisplayStyle.html).Picture.

For example you could use something like the following C# example:

```
void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
{
    // The column ("Department") in the grid will display a ValueList
    // with sample images. The values in this column will be
    // from 0 to 3. 

    // Create a ValueList with three items, one for each color 
    // of the traffic light. 
    Infragistics.Win.ValueList vl = this.GetDepartmentsValueList();
    vl.DisplayStyle = Infragistics.Win.ValueListDisplayStyle.Picture;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        vl.ValueListItems[i].Appearance.Image = this.imageList1.Images[i];
    }

    // Attach this ValueList to the "Department" column in the grid. 
    e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["Department"].ValueList = vl;         

}

private Infragistics.Win.ValueList GetDepartmentsValueList()
{
    Infragistics.Win.ValueList vl = new Infragistics.Win.ValueList();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        vl.ValueListItems.Add(i, string.Format("Department {0}", i) );
    }
    return vl;
}
```

Note that this will limit the number of image objects that are created if you are using the same image multiple times for multiple rows.  This example also uses an image list so that Dispose will be called on the images as this will help prevent memory leaks.